# Eclipse IDE Ctrl + Backspace not working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Eclipse Java IDE for Web Developers (Oxygen.3a.Release (4.7.3a)) on Ubuntu 16.04.4 and within code I am unable to delete the previous word relative to my text pointer. The command is supposed to be `Ctrl + Backspace`, but this doesn't work. The command `Ctrl + Del` does not work either.

Is this a known problem/bug? Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, if you filter on **Ctrl+Backspace** (rather than **delete**) are there any additional mappings defined for that binding?

Comment: @skomisa Nope, just one when I do that. I do have two though for `Ctrl+Delete`: Category Text Editing when Editing Text and SQL Results View when In Windows.

Comment: OK, that seems fine. Perhaps you could try modifying the binding for **Delete Previous Word** from **Ctrl+Backspace** to some other unused value that does not involve the use of **Backspace** (or **Del**), perhaps **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P**, just to see whether that works. If so, then the issue may be related to the use of **Ctrl+Backspace** in your Ubuntu environment (rather than an Eclipse issue) since this works for me on Windows 10. But if you still can't get this to work after changing the binding to something which is fairly unusual I guess a bug report to Eclipse would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

So this is a bug, but it's fixable.

1. Restart Eclipse
2. In the Welcome Window, un-check the "Always show Welcome on start-up" box in the lower right corner.
3. Restart Eclipse again.
4. If that doesn't work try restarting just one more time (that fixed it for me)

Hope that's helpful for anyone in a similar situation!